# Create dataframes from a dictionary of names and dataframes

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

Tried my best looking for a similar answer, but didn't seem to find the necessary one.

I have a dictionary of dataframe objects, where the key is the dataframe name, and the value is the actual dataframe

```
table_names_dict = {'name_1': dataframe_1, 'name_2': dataframe_2}
```

I am trying to loop over the dictionary and dynamically create separate dataframes, using the keys as their names:

```
name_1 = dataframe_1
name_2 = dataframe_2
```

I tried something of the sort

```
for key, value in table_names_dict.items():
     key = value
```

This simply created one dataframe named value

I've also tried

```
locals().update(table_names_dict)
```

Which did create the necessary variables, but they are not accessible in Spyders variable explorer, and from what I've read, the use of locals() is frowned upon.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What you are trying to do doesn't really make sense. Let's suppose you achieve what you aim. What would you then go on to do with it? Can you explain the bigger picture?

Comment: Then I have my dataframes as separate objects which I can easily manipulate using one line of code for each respective one. They are in a dictionary since I imported them that way from a database

Comment: You can manpulate each one already by doing `do_something_with_dataframe(table_names_dict['name_1'])`.

Comment: For instance, if I need to nullify I column in a df?   
Old way: dname_1['column name'] = np.nan    

New way: How do I access that specific column?  

Can't figure it out, if you  can direct me to something I can read about the topic, would be grateful.

Comment: You can do `(table_names_dict['name_1'])['column name'] = np.nan`. Though I accept it can get ugly quickly. If the dataframes are related it's best to glue (`merge`, `concat`, etc) them together into one large dataframe and work with that.

Comment: Nope, they are completely unrelated, and I will need to later export the modified dataframes somewhere else. Thanks for the tip though, I think I am starting to get the hang of it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use globals() for this:

```
for i in table_names_dict:    
    globals()[i]=table_names_dict[i]
```

Comment: Thought about it, but isn't that even more frowned upon than locals()?

Comment: Not many alternatives if you necessarily want to do this